# Using Firebase cloud functions callable

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to use the admin sdk to check for a user phone number. when i check for a number in the database, it displays the result, but when i input a number not in the database, it throws an internal error.

below is a sample code of the functions index.js

```
        const functions = require('firebase-functions');
        const admin = require('firebase-admin');
        admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

          exports.checkPhoneNumber = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
            const phoneNumber = await admin.auth().getUserByPhoneNumber(data.phoneNumber);
            return phoneNumber;
          })
```

front-end.js

```
          toPress = () => {
            const getNumberInText = '+12321123232';

            const checkPhone = Firebase.functions.httpsCallable('checkPhoneNumber');
            checkPhone({ phoneNumber: getNumberInText }).then((result) => {
              console.log(result);
            }).catch((error) => {
              console.log(error);
            });
          }
```

below is the error i am getting when i input a number thats not in the auth

```
- node_modules\@firebase\functions\dist\index.cjs.js:59:32 in HttpsErrorImpl
- node_modules\@firebase\functions\dist\index.cjs.js:155:30 in _errorForResponse

- ... 14 more stack frames from framework internals
```

Comment: Can you share the error you are getting ? Also why don't you make a simple query to check for the phone number, and if you get an empty response it means the number does not exist. This would probably save you the trouble.

Comment: I have added the error to the above description
how do mean make a simple query to check for the phone number, and if you get an empty response it means the number does not exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you will read in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors_on_the_client) of Callable Cloud Functions:

> The client receives an error if the server threw an error or if the resulting promise was rejected.
>
> If the error returned by the function is of type [`function.https.HttpsError`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_https_.httpserror), then the client receives the error code, message, and details from the server error. **Otherwise**, the error contains the message `INTERNAL` and the code `INTERNAL`.

Since you don't specifically manage errors in your Callable Cloud Function, you receive an INTERNAL error.

---

So, if you want to get more details in your front-end, you need to handle the errors in your Cloud Function, as explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors) in the doc.

For example, you could modify it as follows:

```
exports.checkPhoneNumber = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

    try {
        const phoneNumber = await admin.auth().getUserByPhoneNumber(data.phoneNumber);
        return phoneNumber;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.code);
        if (error.code === 'auth/invalid-phone-number') {
            throw new functions.https.HttpsError('not-found', 'No user found for this phone number');
        }
    }
})
```

We throw an error of type `not-found` (See all the possible Firebase Functions status codes [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_https_.html#functionserrorcode)) in case the error code returned by the [`getUserByPhoneNumber()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth#get-user-byphone-number) method is `auth/invalid-phone-number` (See all the possible error codes [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/errors)).

You could refine this error handling code, by treating other errors returned by `getUserByPhoneNumber()` and sending to the client other specific status codes.

Comment: thanks man... I have done as you explained above and also read the documentation, this time no error is displayed. but in firebase cloud function console, the log is displayed. But its not showing anything at the front-end

Comment: fixed it...thanks, the errorcode was user-not-found

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way I usually use to check if a field (ex. phone) exists in any of the documents in my collection.

For an example based on what you described here is a collection I have created:

[image]

The code to make a query for checking if a phone exists looks like this: (I'm using Node.Js)

```
let collref = db.collection('posts');

var phoneToCheck = '+123456789'
const phone1 = collref.where('phone', '==', phoneToCheck)

let query1 = phone1.get()
  .then(snapshot => {
    if (snapshot.empty) {
      console.log('No matching documents.');
      return;
    }

    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
      console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
    });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('Error getting documents', err);
  });
```

If a Document exists with that phone number the response is like this:

[image]

I no document has that phone number then the response is the following:

[image]